# How can I use my new relic account outside Heroku?

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I have configured a `New Relic` account for a Rails app hosted on `Heroku`. Now I want to access the `New Relic` site directly to setup monitoring for an application not hosted on `Heroku`. The problem is that it doesn't allow me to sign-up or sign in with my email because it says I already exist with that email.

Do I have to create an independent account with `New Relic`? Is there a way to manage `Heroku` and non-`Heroku` apps with the same account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use both Heroku and non-Heroku apps with New Relic. Your best bet will be to open a ticket at http://support.newrelic.com and they'll help you out.

Once you're set up, you will land in the non-Heroku account when you log in, but then can switch to the Heroku account. (Links into your Heroku account will work as expected, too.)